# apt - use "provided" packages

Tags: apt, package-management, java

Using Kubuntu.

```
cat /etc/issue

Ubuntu 17.04 \n \l
```

Now let's assume we have installed the default-jdk package:

```
apt show default-jdk

Package: default-jdk
Version: 2:1.8-57ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Source: java-common (0.57ubuntu1)
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Java Maintainers <pkg-java-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 6'144 B
Provides: java-sdk, java2-sdk, java5-sdk, java6-sdk, java7-sdk, java8-sdk
Depends: default-jre (= 2:1.8-57ubuntu1), default-jdk-headless (= 2:1.8-57ubuntu1), openjdk-8-jdk
Homepage: https://wiki.debian.org/Java/
Supported: 9m
Download-Size: 968 B
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Description: Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit
 This dependency package points to the Java runtime, or Java compatible
 development kit recommended for this architecture, which is
 openjdk-8-jdk for amd64.
```

It says here "provides java7-sdk". How do I use that sdk?

Comment: Add manually it to intelliJ using settings I think!

Comment: @George and if I wanted to use it from commandline, e.g. as part of a build/run script?

Comment: Add the path to the commandline!

Comment: @George Yeah, thank you very much ... I don't suppose you could tell me WHAT path? Because without that, I know just as much as before.